# Encoding string to Windows-1252 URL format in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode, urlencode

I want to represent all characters in a string as in this 
[table](https://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php).

But when I do

```
raw = 'æøå'
encoded = raw.encode('cp1252')
print(encoded)
```

I get

```
>>> b'\xe6\xf8\xe5'
```

What I want is

```
>>> %E6%F8%E5
```

as a string for use in a URL.

Comment: There's no such thing. 1252 is the Latin codepage. *URLs* though have their *own* encoding, unrelated to codepages. You are asking how to URL-encode that string.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Latin-1 is a different standard. CP-1252 differs from that standard, don't equate the two. You are completely right about this not being CP1252 encoded output, of course.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I know but I'm tired of writing an entire article to describe encodings in comments for the Nth time. The OP is still asking the wrong thing, confusing character codepages for URL encoding

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: absolutely. And `urllib.parse.quote()` takes care of encoding for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to "quote" your string using urllib tools.

```
import urllib.parse

raw = 'æøå'
print(urllib.parse.quote(raw, encoding='cp1252'))
# returns "%E6%F8%E5"
```

Comment: You do not need to encode separately. `urlib.parse.quote()` takes an encoding argument directly.

Comment: Use `urllib.parse.quote(raw, encoding='cp1252')`, skip the `raw.encode()` call altogether.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the information, I just discovered this. Answer updated

Comment: Sometimes you do need to handle `bytes`, at which point I'd recommend you use [`urllib.parse.quote_from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_from_bytes), to be explicit about what is being done. Also, the OP probably wants to use `quote_plus()`, not `quote()`, as the vast majority of these want the [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application/x-www-form-urlencoded_type).